# Docker exiting with code 139; what does this mean?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am currently working with Docker Tensorflow. The start up works, data preperation, building the model etc, but when the first epoch starts the container exits with code 139. In the Docker documentation I can't find anywhere what this exit code means! Can someone explain it to me so I can find out where the problem is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker is exited immediately when runs with error code 139](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508604/docker-is-exited-immediately-when-runs-with-error-code-139)

Answer (score 2):

This is typically an indication that your application received a SIGSEGV. Docker is only passing through the error codes, so you need to research your application to understand why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by updating my docker version