# docker is exited immediately when runs with error code 139

Tags: docker, docker-container, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a web api project with running fine when i ran through visual studio, able to build the image also.
but when i run using the command

```
docker run -d -t -p 8000:83 8fbf296e2173
```

shows no error and the container will be listed in `docker ps -a` with the status

```
Exited (139) 1 second ago
```

Please help to solve this

Answer (score 20):

Started using WSL 2 and encountered the same issue. The workaround posted here has resolved things for me:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4694#issuecomment-

Add the following to .wslconfig in *%userprofile%\.wslconfig*

```
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate
```

Comment: thanks @sam-worley, your anwser gave me the right way. Summary: create a file named .wslconfig in the user directory C://users/[your user name]/.wslconfig with content "`[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate`" and restart pc:
https://dev.to/damith/docker-desktop-container-crash-with-exit-code-139-on-windows-wsl-fix-438

Answer (score 12):

It's impossible to say what the root cause is without knowing more about the image that is running. But, the `Exited (139)` basically means the PID 1 of the container was sent `SIGKILL`. It could be anything, segfault, out of memory, stack overflow, etc.

Comment: thanks wmorrell, is any way to log this somewhere the error

Comment: Run `docker inspect [container ID]` using the container ID found in the `docker ps` output. That will dump a big JSON object containing info about that container, potentially including more information on what caused the termination. Also, `docker logs [container ID]`.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone's future reference; Docker exit code `139` (`128 + 11`) means that a container received a `SIGSEGV`. This may be a result of invalid memory reference.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35410993/7160815

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while trying to connect to port 1433 from my host to docker (error code 139). I was able to resolve it by using *Administrator: Windows Powershell*.