# Docker fails to build image with exit code 139

Tags: docker, centos, centos6, wsl-2

I'm trying to build an image from CentOS 6.9. Using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6.9

RUN ls
```

But it keeps failing with exit code 139 with the following output:

```
$ docker build -t centos-6.9 .
[+] Building 1.1s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 72B                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:6.9                                                                                    0.6s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 72B                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/centos:6.9@sha256:6fff0a9edc920968351eb357c5b84016000fec6956e6d745f695e5a34f18ecd2                       0.0s 
 => [2/3] COPY . .                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN ls                                                                                                                           0.3s 
------
 > [3/3] RUN ls:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ls]: exit code: 139
```

I'm running:

- Windows 10 Enterprise Version 2004
- Docker Desktop 3.0.0

Comment: There are also good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508604/docker-is-exited-immediately-when-runs-with-error-code-139

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be an issue with WSL 2 with older base images, not docker or the image itself.

1. Create `%userprofile%\.wslconfig` file.
2. Add the following:

```
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate
```

3. Restart WSL. `wsl --shutdown`
4. Restart Docker Desktop.

References:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4694#issuecomment-556095344
2. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7284#issuecomment-646910923
3. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4694#issuecomment-558335829

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Hyper-V base.

Comment: Could you please specify where to place the file `.wslconfig`?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland In your home directory. If you press Wind + R keys, and put `%userprofile%` it'll open your home folder.